# JProfiler crashes on start

Tags: jprofiler

When I try to start JProfiler 9 on Ubuntu 14 I get this exception:

jprofiler9/bin/jprofiler 
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.SplashScreen.getSplashScreen(SplashScreen.java:117)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.splash.AwtSplashScreen.(AwtSplashScreen.java:17)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.splash.SplashEngine.setJavaSplashScreenConfig(SplashEngine.java:17)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:50)

Is there a work around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This means that you do not have access to an X-server.

On a remote machine without a GUI, you can use `bin/jpenable` to prepare the JVM for profiling and connect with a JProfiler GUI from your desktop machine.

Comment: Huh?  I'm running on Ubuntu 14 which has an x-server and a graphical desktop and lots of graphical applications.

Comment: In any case you're starting the executable in such a way that java thinks there is no X-server.